# Firebase - get childrens of children

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am looking for a good solution to take data from a child of children.

As You can see in my "users" database i have nodes with users uid's, and in this nodes i have stored users data such as avatar, username etc. but i have problem with getting data from example "followers" node - So far I have been creating a new OnChildAddedListener in main OnChildAddedListener (listener for "users" node) but I am 100% sure I am doing it wrong - among other things because I never know when all the data has been loaded.

Database Structure:

- Users (NODE)

  - User uid (NODE)

    - username (string)
    - avatar (string)
    - firstname (string)
    - lastname (string)
    - followers (NODE) <- How to get data from this node without making new OnChildListener
    - albums (NODE) <- Same as "followers"

[image]

The way I tried to do it

```
FirebaseDatabase database;
        DatabaseReference userReference;
        DatabaseReference userFollowersReference;

        String loggedUserUid = "uid"; // Logged User UID

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("url");
        userReference = database.getReference("users").child(loggedUserUid);
        userFollowersReference = database.getReference("users").child(loggedUserUid).child("followers");

        userReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                String username = snapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
                String avatar = snapshot.child("avatar").getValue(String.class);
            }
        });

        userFollowersReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                List<String> followers = new ArrayList<>();

                followers.add(snapshot.child("followerUid").getValue(String.class));
            }
        });
```

So - is there a simpler and a better looking way to not clutter the code and to know when all the needed data is loaded?

Comment: Listeners on a node always get all nested child nodes and all changes to those nodes over time.  You shouldn't have to write any more code to get them.  Maybe you should show your code and explain in more detail what's not working the way you expect with it.  Please read about how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm with Doug here: what you want is possible, so the problem is likely in your implementation. Please edit your question to include the [minimal code with which we can reproduce where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug and Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated the post with the code - the problem is that I create a new `ChildAddedListener` for each node - it's ugly and i need to do some workarounds to know when all data is loaded, and I'm not too sure how to write the code to get all nodes and sub-nodes in one `ChildAddedListener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snapshot contains everything in the node where you attached the listener.  You just need to dig into it to find all the data.

```
snapshot
    .child("username")
    .child("followers")
    .child("followerUid")
    .getValue(String.class);
```

Comment: But this will only return one follower, and there will be more than one.

Comment: Then use the getter method that returns a list instead of a string.  The data is all there in the snapshot.